# Improving data structure

Tags: linked-list, runtime, time-complexity, doubly-linked-list

If I have a data structure that acting like a stack, which I implemented using Doubly Linked list, I also added a pointer which always keeps the middle element.

I want to modify it by adding a method peekAt(k) which will return the Kth inserted element, in O(log(k)).

[image: linked list]

Any ideas how can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you implemented it as a `double linked list`, you cannot return `k-th` elementh in `O(log(k))` time, because linked list doesn't have a random access to elements. I suggest implementing your stack as an `(dynamic) array` instead where you can achieve `O(1)` access.

**EDIT:**

If you want also fast `insertion / deletion` in any place, then I suggest using a `balanced binary tree`.

Comment: The insertion and removal have to be in O(1), which is impossible with dynamic array.